# My massages are not delivered to a particular contact on Whatsapp

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, ios, samsung-galaxy-a8-2018

I have a friend. He lives in Finland and uses WhatsApp on his iOS Phone. I'm in Iran and use WhatsApp for Android on my Galaxy A8.
Over the past few months, our ability to communicate through this app has deteriorated. He says he doesn’t receive my messages, apparently he can’t see them. This is frustrating, to say the least, and puts a lot of unneeded stress on both of us.
He says that I'm the only one this happens to, and that communication with his Iranian contacts works just fine.
I'm really clueless. I've scoured the Internet for answers, but I can't seem to find any. I send messages, and in the time they delivered to my friend, after 2 or 3 days. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app countless times, and my network connection at my house is perfect. But this seems to only be getting worse. I send him several messages a day, but I only get some of the messages about every other day--usually every two days.
I'm not a tech by any means, but it seems like there might be something wrong with the different versions of WhatsApp. Android communicating with the iOS Phone. So if this is the case, then my question here is unneeded. I've contacted WhatsApp Inc. with my concerns but not get any appropriate answer

Comment: https://signal.org

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking about why my massages are delivered to my friend in Finland after 2-3 days and how can I solve this problem??